# Create report in MVC using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I need a report that shows the number of unique visitors each day. Here is the query:

```
SELECT User.Name
       ,Visit.VisitDate
       ,COUNT(Visit.Id) AS NumOfVists
FROM Visit JOIN User ON Visit.UserId = User.Id
GROUP BY User.Name, Visit.VisitDate
```

I have created the User(table) model and the Visit(table) model using code-first. I also have the dbcontext class which references these two models(tables). In my controller, I need to pass the results of this query into a View.

First of all, do I have to create a MODEL of this recordset? If yes, do I create a model named say, REPORT with 3 members called Name, VisitDate, and NumOfVisits?

If that's the case, what will the LINQ version of this query look like? and how do I pass it to the view?

Comment: It really looks like you haven't tried to solve this yourself.  You're asking us to solve this issue for you, but I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and presume you're still learning MVC.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without knowing your exact schema, or how you want the result to be arranged, but I think the LINQ version of that would be something like:

```
from u in User
from v in u.Visit
group v by new { u.Name, v.VisitDate } into g
select new {g.Key.Name, g.Key.VisitDate, Count = g.Count()};
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable<x>` result, where `x` is an anonymous type with three members: a string, a DateTime, and an Int. You don't need to create a ViewModel for this, but you can if you want to:

```
from u in User
from v in u.Visit
group v by new { u.Name, v.VisitDate } into g
select new MyViewModel
{
    Name = g.Key.Name, 
    VisitDate = g.Key.VisitDate, 
    Count = g.Count()
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but are the first two lines of your LINQ expression correct? Both User and Visit are tables... so how can u.Visit exist? Here is what I have so far.. for the first two lines: from u in User
join v in Visit on u.Id equals v.UserId into j.. how do I connect that with the grouping part?

Comment: @ebeygin - That's why I say it depends on your schema. If your User objects contain a collection of Visits, you should do it this way. Otherwise, just replace the second line with `join v in Visit on u.Id equals v.UserId`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the results of your query directly into the view.  You don't need to create anything extra for it, but can if you want to.  As for how to pass it into the view use

```
return View(your model);
```

Comment: But what's my model? what type is the results of my query? because a View only accepts a model

Comment: A model is just an object, nothing special.  The result of your query depends on how you call it.  It can be anything from a dataset, datareader, anonymous object, custom object.  

When you receive the result of your query, you can put it into another object or just send it over to the view.  It's up to you to decide how to do it, there is no single answer to that.

Post the LINQ or ADO code you come up with to execute the query, and then we can help answer your question better.